# If I update more than 10+ items through updateChildren() method to firebase, my app UI is frozen or not responding

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  RootRef.child("LatestMessages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Messages messages = snapshot.getValue(Messages.class);

                        if (messages.getFrom() != null) {
                            if (messages.getFrom().equals(messageReceiverID) && !messages.isIsseen()) {

                                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                                hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                                snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                                seenChatList();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

If I update more than 10+ items through updateChildren() method to firebase, my app UI is frozen or become not responding.

I need to mark each and every message as true on Firebase when a message is seen by someone.
Please do not suggest marking only the last message as seen because if I do that then on the chat list Activity I will not get the count of all undread messages of a conversation.

The concept is similar to WhatsApp. In the Chat list, I want to show all unread messages count and when I will open the chatbox it should mark as "seen" to firebase for each received message.

Comment: Any network and disk I/O with Firebase happens off the main thread, so it is very unlikely that is causing your UI to be frozen. You might want to troubleshoot a bit more in your code on what part of your code is causing the frozen UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any network and disk I/O with Firebase happens off the main thread, so it is very unlikely that is causing your UI to be frozen. You might want to troubleshoot a bit more in your code on what part of your code is causing the frozen UI.

That said, if you want to reduce the number of API calls to Firebase, you can perform a single multi-location update to accomplish the same:

```
DatabaseReference ref = RootRef.child("LatestMessages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Messages messages = snapshot.getValue(Messages.class);

                if (messages.getFrom() != null) {
                    if (messages.getFrom().equals(messageReceiverID) && !messages.isIsseen()) {
                        updates.put(snapshot.getKey() + "/isseen", true);
                        seenChatList();
                    }
                }
            }

            ref.updateChildren(updates);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: updates.put(snapshot.getKey() + "/isseen", true);

This is already returning full path of firebase to update true right path.

ref.updateChildren(updates); this is refering to wrong path of firebase.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code updates the same paths as yours does, but then with a single update statement. `snapshot.getKey()` returns the key of the child node, so that we can then run the update on `ref` (one level higher). Did you run the code?

Comment: updates.put(snapshot.getKey() + "/isseen", true);

This is already returning the full path of firebase to update "true" to the right path.

ref.updateChildren(updates); this is refering to wrong path of firebase. This is actually duplicating the initial path with user ids.

updates.put("isseen", true);
snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(updates);

when there are multiple messages to update true that time it is initially freezing chatbox UI, and if there are huge unseen messages then it is showing "not responding". @frank

Comment: snapshot.getKey() this is returning not only the child node key but also the whole path of this RootRef.child("LatestMessages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID);

Comment: I've been using this API for more than a couple of years, and have never seen [`DataSnapshot.getKey()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getKey()) return a full path. If it does that for you, can you update your question to show code that does what I've shown here, and logs the keys?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I realized it was changed to getRef(). However, I will check the freezing issue still persist or not and keep you updated.

Comment: I like to update that as per your mentioned code, my issue has been resolved almost. By almost I mean that it is still freezing for a sec when I am opening the chatbox of my app but not crashing this time. I will monitor with a few more testing.